# Using external version.txt for Helm Chart.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When packaging using a [Helm Chart.yaml](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chartyaml-file) you must specify a version.  We would like the chart version to match the apps version.
If there a way to read our existing version.txt file instead of remembering (or not) to update in two places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't.  To confuse things further there's also an `appVersion` field in the `Chart.yaml` file saying what version of the application you're packaging, but it's also near-universal to be able to specify an image tag as a value, with the same effect.

This field is only really used by Helm-specific tooling, for example if this chart is listed as a dependency of other charts or if you're publishing the chart to a central repository.  If you're not doing either of these things you can largely ignore the `version:` field.

If your CI system is publishing the Helm chart to a repository, you might be forced to have it modify the `Chart.yaml` file before publishing it.  A simple `sed` command will work

```sh
sed -i.bak "s/^version:/version: $APP_VERSION/" Chart.yaml
```

but it does become slightly messy to set up.

If you have a more formal "release" process then you would have to remember to update the version number in both places; writing a shell script to update the version numbers (and tag the release in source control, and do whatever other tasks you need) is probably the most straightforward answer.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and used a version of it to set the appVersion.